# regex: Combine 3 regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have 3 regular expressions but perform same action when the pattern matches, so I thought of merging all three expressions into one. I tried a lot but cant get '|' i.e 'or' to work in my regular expression

regex1:  `text.replace(/([\u00A9-\u3299])/g, function myFunction(x){ ... }`

regex2:  `text.replace(/(\uD83C[\uDC04-\uDFF0])/g, function myFunction(x){ ... }`

regex3:  `text.replace(/(\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDEC5])/g, function myFunction(x){ ... }`

I tried doing it but its doesnt work
regex: `text.replace(/([\u00A9-\u3299]) | (\uD83C[\uDC04-\uDFF0]) | (\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDEC5])/g, function myFunction(x){ ... }`

I knw its easy I tried searching a lot but no luck for me.

Comment: Every character counts, you can't put spaces just because it's prettier

Comment: Yeah it works now, I feel such a noob. My updated regex: `text.replace(/([\u00A9-\u3299]|\uD83C[\uDC04-\uDFF0]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDEC5])/g, function myFunction(x){ ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Writing_a_regular_expression_pattern) language is a very strict one, with every character being significative, even spaces (a  matches a space).

Remove the spaces:

```
/[\u00A9-\u3299]|\uD83C[\uDC04-\uDFF0]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDEC5]/g
```

(yes, you can also remove the useless parenthesis in this case, as there's no point defining a group for the whole expression)